# Import a CSV file from a URL to Google Sheets and update it periodically

Tags: csv, import, google-sheets

I'm looking to pull data from a CSV file that gets update regularly into a Google spreadsheet that I can format the way I want. I know how to import the CSV as a one time thing but I don't know how to get it to update the data once it changes in the original CSV.

It doesn't have to update in real time, just periodically, i.e. once an hour or so. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the IMPORTDATA() built-in function.

AFAIK the refresh of the data is done on the server side, so refreshing or recalculating the spreadsheet very frequently could not make any difference. The time that it takes on the server side is not documented in an canonical source; some sources say that it takes 5 minutes others 1 hour.

**References**
[IMPORTDATA - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en)
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/GcDsNPb4NXk/YjE4BzdnZLoJ - Jan 2015
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/ADZnVj-mFnA/Bonn7xucaK8J - 2010